# How to fix Homebrew error "/usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin"

Tags: macos, homebrew

I am sure this is not a new question, and have ben answered on this website before. I have tried the solutions prescribed but unfortunately the error is still persisting. Hence, approaching the community again.

The problem is that HomeBrew gives the warning as follows:

Warning: /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin
This means that system-provided programs will be used instead of those
provided by Homebrew. The following tools exist at both paths:

```
iconv
```

Consider amending your PATH so that /usr/local/bin
occurs before /usr/bin in your PATH.

My /etc/paths looks like this:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

My ~/.bash_profile looks like this:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
```

My ~/.bashrc looks like this:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

My echo $PATH output looks like this:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin /usr/local/rvm/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin     /usr/local/bin /opt/sm/bin /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin /opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin /opt/local/bin
```

Comment: IIRC, the paths are actually some kind of weird queue. Try putting `/usr/local/bin` AFTER `/usr/bin` in your paths file. This may be completely wrong, but something from my teens is triggering my spidey sense.

Comment: Do you really get all the spaces in your output for *echo $PATH*? Or is it just a formatting error? in which shell are you outputting your PATH? *bash*?

Comment: I have the same issue. The only thing I can imagine is mangling my $PATH is this rvm script. I need `/usr/local/bin` before '/usr/bin'

Comment: What happen if you remove all the exports and just leave the one in `/etc/paths`?